# Create a BibTeX style formatting function

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I would like to hack a new BibTeX style file based on `plain.bst`, in which I make it possible to display the value of a `location` field in the `inproceedings` entry type.  I have started as follows:

1. I have added `location` to the list of defined fields in the `ENTRY` block.
2. In `FUNCTION{inproceedings}`, I have simply inserted the line `location output` right after where it prints the `booktitle`.

This works!  However, now I would like simply to enclose the value of `location` in parentheses.  I have tried defining a `FUNCTION{format.location}`, but I don't understand the BibTeX language well enough to get this right.  Any suggestions for the function?  And how do I call it in `FUNCTION{inproceedings}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution could look like:

```
FUNCTION {format.location}
{
  location empty$
    {}
    {"(" location * ")" *}
    if$
    output
}
```

The function works as follows: first of all it looks whether `location` has been given for the entry (`location empty$`). If the test fails (i.e., there is a value for `location`), then

1. it puts `(` on the stack,
2. it puts `location` on the stack,
3. `*` concatenates the last two elements on the stack and puts the outcome on the stack. So after this step we have `(<location>`
4. puts `)` on the stack
5. `*` concatenates the last two elements on the stack and puts the outcome on the stack. So after this step we have `(<location>)`

The last step `output` check the current state, and includes the appropriate punctuation.